# Greenleaf Database Library in C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, clipper

I am creating a WPF application that will integrate with an existing system using a Clipper database.  I have been working through some issues trying to access char fields with lengths greater than 255.  The Jet and FoxPro OLEDB providers seem to cut off the data in these larger fields.  I have modified and used the DotNetDBF library but it does not contain searching capabilities.

The existing applications in this system use the Greenleaf Database Library which is a 32-bit Windows DLL written in C++.  It does contain searching capablilities and also allows me to take advantage of the index files used in the system.

Does anyone know of a .Net/C# wrapper that exists for this library?  Any other alternative library suggestions would also be welcome.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Hi, I suppose that it would be a rather good idea to add a tag "C#" to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at Codebase for .net.

http://www.codebase.com/products/features/?pid=google-xbase_content-c1#xBASE-s-ggkey_xbase